# Cómo modificar los datos de una celda con javascript o cualquier otro metodo

Tags: php, javascript, html

por favor, ¿podrían ayudarme con este código? 
tengo mi tabla con mis datos de mi base de datos en una ventana modal yo transfiero todos esos datos a mi otra tabla que esta bacia en la pagina principal ahora una ves ya pasado mis datos de la tabla en la ventana modal a la tabla de mi pagina proincipal quiero editar mi tabla que esta en la pagina principal es una pagina para hacer una factura donde colocare mis productos y calcular su valor sacrale el iva y todas esa cosas pero estoy enredado en como editar los valores agregados digamos que ya no es ese precios es otro entonses modificar ese valor y que me calcule con la cantidad.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Ingreso de Mercadería</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Website CSS style -->
        <link href="../css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Website Font style -->
        <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">     
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css">
       <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/categoria.css">
    </head>
<body>
  <header>

      <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark" >

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="sistema.php">Stock Web</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Compras</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="ingresomercaderia.php"><img class="img-ico" src="../icono/svg/si-glyph-trolley-arrow-down.svg"> Ingreso de mercaderia</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Ventas</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="Registro_clientes.php"><img class="img-ico" src="../icono/svg/si-glyph-person-plus.svg">Registro de Clientes</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="registro_proveedor.php"><img class="img-ico" src="../icono/svg/si-glyph-person-plus.svg">Registro de Proveedor</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="registro_producto.php"><img class="img-ico" src="../icono/svg/si-glyph-person-plus.svg">Registro de Producto</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="registro_categoria.php"><img class="img-ico" src="../icono/svg/si-glyph-person-plus.svg">Registro de Categoría</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="registro_subcategoria.php"><img class="img-ico" src="../icono/svg/si-glyph-person-plus.svg">Registro de Subcategoría</a>


                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                   <?php 
                     if(isset($_SESSION["is_ok"])){

                           if($_SESSION["is_admin"]){

                              echo $_SESSION["name"]." (Admin)";

                              }

                              else{

                              echo $_SESSION["name"]." (Vendedor)";

                               }
                          }          
                    ?>
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="cambio.php"><img class="img-ico" src="../icono/svg/si-glyph-id-badge.svg"> Cambiar contraseña</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../logica_datos/salir.php"><img class="img-ico" src="../icono/svg/si-glyph-delete.svg"> Cerrar Sesión</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </nav>
  </header>

  <section id="contact">
        <div class="section-content">
          <br>
          <h1 class="section-header">Ingreso  de<span class="content-header wow fadeIn " data-wow-delay="0.2s" data-wow-duration="2s"> Mercadería</span></h1>
          <div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#guardarproducto">Guardar</button>
        </div>
        <br>

        <!-- Modal nuevo -->

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <label for="namecodigo">Código</label>  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textcodigo" placeholder="CÓDIGO" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <label for="namenum">N°</label>  
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textnum" placeholder="NÚMERO" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <label for="nameproveedor">Proveedor</label>
                        <select class="custom-select form-control"  id="textproveedor">
                        <option selected>Seleccione ....</option>
                          <?php
                              include('../Conexion/conexion.php');

                              $consul="SELECT * from tb_proveedor where visible='t'";
                              $resu=pg_query($consul);
                              $numre=pg_num_rows($resu);

                              if ($resu>0) {

                                while ( $prove= pg_fetch_array($resu)) {
                               echo "<option value=".$prove['codigo_prove'].">".$prove['ruc']."</option>";

                              }

                                } 
                                else{
                                  echo "No hay registro";
                                }       
                          ?>
                      </select required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <label for="namefecha">Fecha</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textfecha" placeholder="FECHA" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <label for="namefact">T Fact</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textfact" placeholder="TIPO FACTURA" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <label for="nameconcepto">Concepto</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textconcepto" placeholder="CONCEPTO DE LA MERCADERIA" required>
                      </div>

                        <!-- <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <label for="namedetalle">Detalle</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textdetalle" placeholder=" DETALLE DEL PRODUCTO" required>
                        </div> -->                        
                  </div>
    <br>     
             <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nuevoModal" class="table-add">Agregar Producto</button>
              </div>

            </div>


<br>
        <div class="container">   
          <div class="main-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="target" class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
                  <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th> 

                    </tr>
                  </thead>
              <tbody> 
                  </tbody>
                </table> 
               </div>
             </div> 
         </div>
        </div>

  </section>





    <!-- Modal Agregar -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="nuevoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="nuevoModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="nuevoModalLabel">Agregar Producto</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">

              <div class="container">   
          <div class="main-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="mercaderia" class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
                  <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr >
                      <th>Código</th>
                      <th>Categoría</th>
                      <th>Detalle</th>
                      <th>Stock</th>
                      <th>P.V.P Pack</th>
                      <th>P.V.P Unit</th> 
                      <th>Acciones</th>  
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="myTable">
                <?php         

                      //tomamos los datos del archivo conexion.php  
                      include('../Conexion/conexion.php'); 
                        #selecciono las categorias
                        $consu = pg_query($conexion, "select * from productos where visible_pro='t';");
                          if(pg_num_rows($consu)==0){

                          echo "<tr><td>No existen Producto registradas</td></tr>";
                          }
                          else{
                          #si hay categorias se muestras fila por fila
                          while ($row = pg_fetch_row($consu)) {
                        echo "<tr>
                              <td>".$row[0]."</td>
                              <td>".$row[1]."</td>
                              <td>".$row[2]."</td>
                              <td>".$row[3]."</td>
                              <td>".$row[4]."</td>
                              <td>".$row[5]."</td>
                                      <td>
        <button onclick='add(this)' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>
          Agregar
        </button>
      </td>
                                  </tr>";    

                          }  
                        }


                ?> 

                  </tbody>
                </table> 
               </div>
             </div> 
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <br>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Aceptar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  </section>


<!-- FOOTER -->
            <footer class="container">
                 <p class="float-right"><a href="ingresomercaderia.php">Volver arriba</a></p>
                <p>&copy; 2018 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacidad</a> &middot; <a href="#">Condiciones</a></p>
            </footer>

<!-- SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function add(button) {
    var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
  var cells = row.querySelectorAll('td:not(:last-of-type)');
  addToCartTable(cells);
}

function remove() {
    var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  document.querySelector('#target tbody')
                .removeChild(row);
}

function addToCartTable(cells) {
   var code = cells[0].innerText;
   var name = cells[2].innerText;
   var price = cells[5].innerText;

   var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
   newRow.setAttribute('data-price', price.substring(1));

   newRow.appendChild(createCell(code));
   newRow.appendChild(createCell(name));
   newRow.appendChild(createCell(price));


   // var cellprecio = createCell();
   // cellprecio.appendChild(createprecio(price));
   // newRow.appendChild(cellprecio);

   var cellInputQty = createCell();
   cellInputQty.appendChild(createInputQty());
   newRow.appendChild(cellInputQty);

   var celltotal = createCell();
   celltotal.appendChild(createCell());
   newRow.appendChild(celltotal);


   var cellRemoveBtn = createCell();
   cellRemoveBtn.appendChild(createRemoveBtn())
   newRow.appendChild(cellRemoveBtn);

   document.querySelector('#target tbody').appendChild(newRow);
}

function createInputQty() {
    var inputQty = document.createElement('input');
  inputQty.type = 'number';
  inputQty.required = 'true';
  inputQty.className = 'form-control';
  inputQty.min = 1; // mínimo un producto
  inputQty.onchange = onQtyChange;
  return inputQty;
}

// function createprecio() {
//   var inputQty = document.createElement('input');

//   inputQty.type = 'number';
//   inputQty.required = 'true';
//   inputQty.className = 'form-control';
//   inputQty.min = 1; // mínimo un producto
//   inputQty.id='precio';

//   inputQty.onchange = onQtyChange;
//   return inputQty;
// }

function createRemoveBtn() {
    var btnRemove = document.createElement('button');
  btnRemove.className = 'btn btn-xs btn-danger';
  btnRemove.onclick = remove;
  btnRemove.innerText = 'Descartar';
  return btnRemove;
}

function createCell(text) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
  if(text) {
    td.innerText = text;
  }
  return td;
}

function onQtyChange(e) {
  var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var cellPrice = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(5)');
  var prevPrice = parseFloat(row.getAttribute('data-price'));
  var newQty = Number(this.value);
  alert(prevPrice);
  var total = prevPrice * newQty;
  cellPrice.innerText = '$' + total;

}




</script>

    <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script> 

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.12.4.js" ></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="../js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="../js/mercaderia.js" ></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera, tal y como esta no se entiende bien. Saludos.

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta....

Comment: lo que quiero es modificar los datos que aparescan en mi tabla pro no la del modal si no la que se agregan en la oytra tabla de html

Comment: Saludos @KevinJacho. Creo que lo ideal sería que modificaras tu pregunta intentando explicar mejor cual es tu problema. Nos das una breve descripción que no se entiende muy bien y mucho código.

Comment: ¿Puedes formular mejor la pregunta?, lo que entiendo es que quieres modificar un registro dentro de la base de datos desde un columna o fila de una tabla html, de ser así puedes utilizar la librería [jQuery-jeditable](https://jeditable.elabftw.net/).

Comment: no vera no quiero editar nada en la base de datos solo quiero modificar la tabla osea en ves del valor que esta ahi cambiar ponerle otro numero en la tabla principal no en la tabla del modal la tabla del modal es solo para agregarla a la otra tabla una ves puesto en esa tabla poder modificar para despues guardar en otra vase de datos